# grep включает в диапазон [а-яё] заглавные буквы (или как написать регулярное выражение для строчных русских букв?)

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, grep

При вводе следующей команды в терминале:

```
echo 'ПРИВЕТ' | grep '[а-яё]'
```

у меня выводится «ПРИВЕТ», то есть под регулярное выражение `[а-яё]` подошли заглавные русские буквы.

---

**Как сделать, чтобы под `[а-яё]` в grep подходили только строчные русские буквы?**

---

Используется `ru_RU.UTF-8` локаль:

```
% locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

---

Дополнительная информация:

```
% grep --version; locale -a | grep -i utf; echo 'Аа' | env -i LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8 grep -o '[а]'
grep (GNU grep) 3.3
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others; see
<https://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
ru_RU.utf8
а
```

---

Дополнительная информация (`$SHELL` равна `/bin/zsh`, но в zsh эта команда не заработала, так как у меня grep это алиас на `grep --color=auto`, поэтому запустил команду в bash (также проверил, что в bash ошибка воспроизводится)):

```
$ echo $SHELL; $(ldd $(which grep) | grep 'libc\.so' | awk '{print $3}')
/bin/zsh
GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.28.
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 8.2.1 20180831.
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC ABSOLUTE
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.archlinux.org/>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92364/discussion-on-question-by-user268670-grep-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

получен ответ от upstream в [Bug 23393 - Handle [a-z] and [A-Z] in consistent portable fashion regardless of locale](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23393#c41).

---

кратко:

интервалы в не-posix/c локалях не определены, потому [это не баг (с точки зрения поддерживающего пакет в дистрибутиве debian)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=926906). но они (разработчики glibc) [по]пытаются сделать лучше.

---

[подробно](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23393#c41) (главное выделено мной):

> Carlos O'Donell 2019-08-19 14:27:18 UTC
>
> This user is expecting the range to be made up of collation ordering, and that expectation is not valid. The range in any non-POSIX/C locale is undefined.
>
> Therefore the bug you reference is not a bug, but it's still difficult for users to use ranges without problems, and that makes them relatively useless and we'd like to fix that. The plan is to fix this with rational ranges that use UTF-8 code-point ordering for all ranges.
>
> The deinterleaving for LATIN is consciously to fix only the ASCII ranges and fix POSIC/C ranges. All other ranges are undefined. If we deinterlace non-LATIN ranges we'd have to duplicate all the data into the individual locales and list them in collation order (so collation order matches collation element ordering). Such a change would be quite drastic, and still not solve the problem of having collation changes change range expressions. It also wouldn't solve the broader problem that everyone still expects [a-z] to work all the time (code-point ordering).
>
> **I would close your debian bug as an unsupported configuration for ranges, but point out that we are trying to make this better.**